# C++: Vector3 type "wall"?

Tags: c++

Say I have:

```
class Vector3 {
  float x, y, z;
  ... bunch of cuntions ..
  static operator+(const Vector3&, const Vector3);
};
```

Now, suppose I want to have classes:

```
Position, Velocity,
```

that are exactly like Vector3 (basically, I want

```
typedef Vector3 Position;
typedef Vector3 Velocity;
```

Except, given:

```
Position position;
Vector3 vector3;
Velocity velocity;
```

I want to make sure the following *can't* happen:

```
position + vector3;
vector3 + velocity;
velocity + position;
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What you want are units, which may not be trivial. Boost has such a thing. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_units.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend something like this:

```
template<typename tag>
class Vector3 {
  float x, y, z;
  ... bunch of functions ..
  static operator+(const Vector3&, const Vector3);
};

struct position_tag {};
struct velocity_tag {};
typedef Vector3<position_tag> Position;
typedef Vector3<velocity_tag> Velocity;
```

See here for a more elaborate example: [Boost MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/dimensional-analysis.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using typedef, you can derive Position & Velocity from Vector3. Then remove operator+ from Vector3, and define it in Position & Velocity.

```
class Vector3 {
  float x, y, z;
  ... bunch of cuntions ..
};

class Position : public Vector3 {
  static Position operator+(const Position&, const Position&);
}

class Velocity : public Vector3 {
  static Velocity operator+(const Velocity&, const Velocity&);
}
```