# C++: type Length from float

Tags: c++, typing

This is kinda like my earlier question:
[C++: Vector3 type "wall"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451175/c-vector3-type-wall)

Except, now, I want to do this to a builtin rather then a user created type.

So I want a type "Length" that behaves just like float -- except I'm going to make it's constructor explicit, so I have to explicitly construct Length objects (rather than have random conversions flying around).

Basically, I'm going into the type-a-lot camp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to wrap a float primitive in your own class. Here's an example to get you started:

```
class Length
{
protected:
    float value_;
public:
    Length(float value) : value_(value) { }
    static Length operator +(Length a, Length b) { return Length(a.value_ + b.value_); }
    static Length operator -(Length a, Length b) { return Length(a.value_ - b.value_); }
    static Length operator *(Length a, Length b) { return Length(a.value_ * b.value_); }
    static Length operator /(Length a, Length b) { return Length(a.value_ / b.value_); }
};
```

But, using the boost Units library is a much better choice in the long run...

Answer (score 3):

Like suggested in a comment over at your other question you can use [units from boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_units.html). This should be explicit and still manageable.

Comment: Thanks GMan. I am never sure what can be done about questions which have very closely related spin-off questions: neither exact duplicates nor bad enough for a downvote, but they still make SO less comprehensible.

Comment: @GMan: I was really looking for answers that are "open box" rather than "use boost"

Comment: @anon: Eh, like I said in my comment, a usable system isn't very trivial. Your best bet would probably look at how boost does it and see if you can strip the important stuff out to keep.